# Designing layout for different tab sizes

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, tabs

I want to design a application for different tablets so i created different layout folders i.e.

- `layout-sw600dp`
- `layout-sw720dp`

Now the problem is that i am testing the application in 2 tabs having `1280x800` & `2048x1536` resolutions respectively and they both fall under `layout-sw720dp` folder only. So how can i differentiate between both of them so that i can draw layouts separately.

Or i just need to get the pixel density and calculate for each and everything to design for these tabs like this :

```
dp = px / (dpi / 160)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "px", "dip", "dp" and "sp"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/what-is-the-difference-between-px-dip-dp-and-sp)

Answer (score 1):

**Please refer to this [DOCUMENTATION](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension) and also this [link](https://material.io/guidelines/layout/units-measurements.html#)**

```
+----------------+----------------+---------------+-------------------------------+
| Density Bucket | Screen Density | Physical Size | Pixel Size                    | 
+----------------+----------------+---------------+-------------------------------+
| ldpi           | 120 dpi        | 0.5 x 0.5 in  | 0.5 in * 120 dpi = 60x60 px   | 
+----------------+----------------+---------------+-------------------------------+
| mdpi           | 160 dpi        | 0.5 x 0.5 in  | 0.5 in * 160 dpi = 80x80 px   | 
+----------------+----------------+---------------+-------------------------------+
| hdpi           | 240 dpi        | 0.5 x 0.5 in  | 0.5 in * 240 dpi = 120x120 px | 
+----------------+----------------+---------------+-------------------------------+
| xhdpi          | 320 dpi        | 0.5 x 0.5 in  | 0.5 in * 320 dpi = 160x160 px | 
+----------------+----------------+---------------+-------------------------------+
| xxhdpi         | 480 dpi        | 0.5 x 0.5 in  | 0.5 in * 480 dpi = 240x240 px | 
+----------------+----------------+---------------+-------------------------------+
| xxxhdpi        | 640 dpi        | 0.5 x 0.5 in  | 0.5 in * 640 dpi = 320x320 px | 
+----------------+----------------+---------------+-------------------------------+
```

If layouts are problem then why don't you try using [SPD library](https://github.com/intuit/sdp) for `margin` `padding` dimens.

> **Using this you may have to make only one layout for all screen sizes**

Comment: i know i can do it by calculating the pixel density thats what i am asking that the only way i can do it is by calculating that for each view only or i can somehow make a different layout separately for both.

Comment: If layouts are problem then why don't you try using https://github.com/intuit/sdp for margin padding dimens. Using this you may have to make only one layout for all screen sizes